# How to export some data from Firebird database with FBExport?

Tags: firebird, fbexport

I'm trying to export some data from a Firebird database, with FBExport to a CSV file.
The problem is I have two different errors. I spent a few hours to try different combinations:

- Unknown switch -
- Switches must begin with -

The command I tried:

```
fbexport -Sc -Q -F h:\AABBCC\export.csv -B -D h:\AABBCC\XXYYZZ.FDB -U "MMNNOO" -P "PPQQRR" -X "select PATIENTS.IPP, PATIENTS.NOM, PATIENTS.NOM_MARITAL, PATIENTS.NOM_USUEL, PATIENTS.PRENOMS, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 from PATIENTS join dmc on PATIENTS.ipp = dmc.CODE where dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2 is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 is not null;"
```

I absolutely don't understand what FBExport needs.
How can I export the data?

Comment: I haven't used FBExport, but looking at the [manual](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/manual.html), I get the feeling you just put random combinations of options in there. What is `-Sc`, it is not listed in the documentation, maybe you meant `-S`? Also you seem to have mixed up the `-X` (eXecute) and `-Q` (Query) options. The `-S` (Save) and `-X` (eXecute) options seem to be mutually exclusive. The `-B` option requires a value for the separator to use. I will see if I can try things out to give an actual answer later, but maybe this will help to resolve things on your own.

Comment: Regarding `-Sc`, I see that means 'export CSV' according to https://github.com/mariuz/fbexport/blob/master/fbexport/ParseArgs.cpp#L163

Comment: Hi, no random mode, Sc seems to be used to export as CSV files. FBExport v1.80 by Milan Babuskov (mbabuskov@yahoo.com), using IBPP 2.5.3.0
Tool for importing/exporting data with Firebird and InterBase databases.
Usage: fbexport -[S|Sc|Si|Sh|I|If|X|L] Options

 -S  Select = output to file  (S - binary, Si - INSERTs, Sc - CSV, Sh - HTML)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed when I looked in the source of a fork. In any case, I think the primary fix is probably removing `-Q` from its current location, replacing `-X` with `-Q` in front of the query, and removing `-B`.

Comment: If I do this command : fbexport -Sc -F h:\AABBCC\export.csv -D h:\DDEEFF\GGHHJJ.FDB -U "KKLLMM" -P "NNOOPP" -X "select PATIENTS.IPP, PATIENTS.NOM, PATIENTS.NOM_MARITAL, PATIENTS.NOM_USUEL, PATIENTS.PRENOMS, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 from PATIENTS join dmc on PATIENTS.ipp = dmc.CODE where dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2 is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 is not null;"  I have "switches must begin with -"

Comment: You need to use `-Q "select ..."` instead of `-X "select ..."`. `-X` doesn't expect arguments, so the `"select ..."` is taken as a new option, but as it doesn't start with a `-`, that is reported as an error.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `-Q` as Query , but I think I allready tested. I will try again tomorrow .  And , one thing , it's an old firebird DB , seems to be 2.1 so it's in dialecte1 .

Comment: I'll see if I can find the time to try it myself as well. As an aside, dialect 1 was deprecated in InterBase 6.0 (before Firebird 1.0) when dialect 3 was introduced, so it being a Firebird 2.1 database doesn't necessarily mean it's dialect 1. That said, even if it is, I don't think it is related to your problem, because it happens when parsing the commandline arguments.

Comment: `seems to be 2.1` - You can check ODS (on-disk structure) with `gstat` command or with tools like IB First Aid (would be printed in file open log) - then you can match it to Firebird versions using article on http://ib-aid.com - however in practice Firebird 2.5 can open but all prior versionsm even ODS as old as of Interbase 5.5. You may usually consider FB 2.5 your swissknife (if you do not want backward compatibiltiy with installed FB2.1 based systems).

Comment: Nex test this morning, if I do : `fbexport -Sc path_to_csv -d path_to_data.FDB -U "USER" -P "PASSWORD" -Q "select PATIENTS.IPP, PATIENTS.NOM, PATIENTS.NOM_MARITAL, PATIENTS.NOM_USUEL, PATIENTS.PRENOMS, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 from PATIENTS join dmc on PATIENTS.ipp = dmc.CODE where dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2 is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 is not null;"`  ; I have this error  `Switches must begin with -`  ... The database is still in production , I assume the version is 2.1.7

Comment: OK, few more information: `ODS Version: 11.1` , `Dialect: 1` , `Default character set: NONE`. But it seems that there is no need space character .... It so stupid... I think that I have a succes if I remove space..

Comment: OK: Succes , so I put here the good command , it could be usefull if some people need to export a firebird database to CSV: `fbexport -Sch:\lisia32\export.csv -Fh:\path_to_export_file\export.csv -Dh:\path_to_db_file.FDB -USYSDBA -Pmasterkey -Q"select PATIENTS.IPP, PATIENTS.NOM, PATIENTS.NOM_MARITAL, PATIENTS.NOM_USUEL, PATIENTS.PRENOMS, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 from PATIENTS join dmc on PATIENTS.ipp = dmc.CODE where dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2 is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 is not null;"`

Comment: The option ` -Sch:\lisia32\export.csv` is incorrect (but silently ignored I think), `-Sc` itself doesn't expect a filename, that is what `-F` is for. In your previous example, the problem was the bare presence of `path_to_csv`, which was interpreted as an option, and as it didn't start with `-` produced the error; it should have been `-F path_to_csv`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following command line works:

```
fbexport -Sc -D employee -U sysdba -P masterkey -F C:\Temp\export.csv -Q "select * from employee"
```

The problem in your original command was that you had a bare `-Q`, which caused the following `-F` to be interpreted as the argument of `-Q`, which then lead to `h:\AABBCC\export.csv` to be interpreted as an option, which then produced an error because it doesn't start with a `-`.

In addition, your command also had the following problems:

- `-B` defines an alternative separator character for the produced CSV. It expects a separator character or `TAB` or `\t` for a tab. So, in similar vein as the previous problem, this would cause `-D` to be interpreted as an argument of `-B`, which then leads to `h:\AABBCC\XXYYZZ.FDB` to be interpreted as an option (without `-`).
- `-X` is a primary option (like `-S`), to execute the query specified by `-Q`, instead of exporting (saving, `-S`). It doesn't accept a query text as argument, so the query text is also interpreted as an option (without `-`). This occurrence of `-X` should have been `-Q`.

Comment: Last thing, the firebird DB is running on a win server 2k8 R2 . Then, i've tried your command (with my own path, and db name, etc ...) and still have this error: `switches must begin with -`  , and if I remove space  it worst . So anyway , I had succes with the command I showed above . Thank you for the time you past on my problem .

Comment: What do you mean with "if i remove space it worst"? If you mean the paths have spaces in them, then you need to enclose that path in double quotes, so that the command line interpreter sends it as one argument, instead of each space separated parts as an individual argument. For example, `-D "C:\path to\yourdatabase.fdb"` or `-F "C:\path to\output.csv"`.

Comment: Not in the path. The only one command that work , for me on my system is this one: `fbexport -Sch:\lisia32\export.csv -Fh:\path_to_export_file\export.csv -Dh:\path_to_db_file.FDB -USYSDBA -Pmasterkey -Q"select PATIENTS.IPP, PATIENTS.NOM, PATIENTS.NOM_MARITAL, PATIENTS.NOM_USUEL, PATIENTS.PRENOMS, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 from PATIENTS join dmc on PATIENTS.ipp = dmc.CODE where dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2 is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 is not null;"` .

Comment: It is not clear to me what you think `-Sch:\lisia32\export.csv` does, that should be just `-Sc`. If you previously tried a command with `-Sc h:\lisia32\export.csv`, then that is the cause of your problem, because that `h:\lisia32\export.csv` is then interpreted as an option, and as it doesn't start with `-`, it produces an error. The output file is specified by `-F <filename>`

Comment: I was lazy  so I change the command to send you the answer, it seems you can put something or not behind -Sc argument, it doesn't change anything `fbexport -Sc -Dpath_to_DB.FDB -U"SYSDBA" -P"masterkey" -Fpath_to_export_test6.csv -Q"select PATIENTS.IPP, PATIENTS.NOM, PATIENTS.NOM_MARITAL, PATIENTS.NOM_USUEL, PATIENTS.PRENOMS, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2, dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 from PATIENTS join dmc on PATIENTS.ipp = dmc.CODE where dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_2 is not null or dmc.NUM_DOSSIER_PAPIER_3 is not null;"`

Comment: I didn't understood if `-Sc` options need a path , so I put the path after . Tomorrow I will try again , 2 command . 1 like `fbexport -Sc -D path_to_db.FDB -U "SYSDBA -P "masterkey" -F path_to_export.csv -Q "my_query"` , and another with something after as `-Sc` just to see if I'll have some error . I think it's important to understand where I'm wrong.